# Non-trivial qt model data manipulation per proxy

Tags: c++, qt

As I began to ask [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32748267/reading-data-in-different-ways-from-the-same-model-in-qt), I`m trying to view the data contained in a single model in Qt differently in different views without having to create more models and without changing it.

To be more specific: I'm trying to take a QString and show it in several tables, letter by letter, with manipulations that would be considered simple in other circumstances.

To name one such manipulation: One table will get the string reversed (this table only has a single row, but a line edit will not work here for program-related reasons) and stripped of any spaces (which **will** remain in the model as they are necessary in other views).

***EDIT:*** To give a more complete and concrete example: Hello World -> Dlrow Olleh.
I want to reverse the capitalization and check for words that are comprised entirely of uppercase letters - those will remain entirely in uppercase.

another planned manipulation is also removing all spaces but this time the table will be a matrix (so I guess some changes to indexing functions will be required).

EDIT2: Please note that the matrix's size will change according to the input's size in order to fit the screen so indexing (at least in the table itself) will not remain the same. If that matters...

I've been trying to figure out how to do this for the past two days and the best I could find (beside reading the Qt documentation, which was of no help) was
[this article](http://blog.qt.io/blog/2012/01/12/qt-commercial-support-weekly-10-sorting-filtering-and-advanced-manipulation-with-proxy-models-2/).

It doesn't, however, explain what each piece of code does well enough and therefore doesn't allow someone like me, who doesn't understand the concept already, to make any alteration for the code to fit my needs.

I could, of course, just create more models and perform all those manipulations outside of the messy underside, but I like to challenge myself and learn something extra whenever possible and find better and more efficient ways to do things.

What do I need to implement in QAbstractProxyModel when subclassing it, and more importantly - how do I do it (explained code would be very appreciated)
in order to create a code that will provide this behavior? (I am aware that each proxy will probably be different)

Comment: so, you have a `QString`, say "Hello World". You want to display "dlroW olleH" in one table and other "HelloWorld" in other table. Am I correct?

Comment: That an oversimplification (I'll do a lot more) but that's the basic idea.

Comment: This question lacks the necessary detail. Please amend it by providing examples of actual modifications you intend. The formal way to describe them is by writing a series of `Q_ASSERT`s: one for the value of `data` on the original model, and one each for the item(s) synthesized by the proxy. For example, for your string reversal and stripping I assume: `Q_ASSERT(model->data(model->index(0,0)).toString() == "Ba Z"); Q_ASSERT(proxy->data(proxy->index(0,0)).toString() == "ZaB");` Please describe other modifications in such terms: these are test cases for any answers you'd get.

Comment: "That an oversimplification (I'll do a lot more) but that's the basic idea." You're asking how to do something specific: you'll need to ask about the real thing you will do, not some simplification of it - unless you wish your answers to cover the simplified case only. We can't divine what you wish. So far you issues seem trivial, but how do we know whether you are looking for a trivial answer or not?

Comment: Besides, the Qt documention *does* provide essentially all you need. The [Model View Programming](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html) chapter lays out the semantics of a model. A proxy is still a model, so it has to fulfill all of a model's contract, no matter where it gets its data from. The `QxxxxProxyModel` classes for convenience of having the boilerplate implemented for you. It's your option to use them. If you have *specific questions* about what a particular method does (or is supposed to do), please ask them separately, otherwise you're just ranting...

Comment: "What do I need to implement in QAbstractProxyModel when subclassing it" An even better question: do you even need to subclass `QAbstractProxyModel` - if you don't know *how* to use it, why do you assume that you've made the right choice *to* use it at all? You're not telling us enough.

Comment: @KubaOber I edited in a concrete example and what I currently believe to be the entirety of what I'm trying to accomplish. Also, the reason I'm simplifying my question is I'm trying to get an answer that will be as broad as possible and give me the most flexible solution. For some cases, and here as well, it seems, this does not work and people get annoyed. Lastly, why do I think I need to use QAbstractProxyModel? Because the premade proxies don't have the functionality I want (of course, you couldn't know that until now) and I really want to learn this flexible(?) mechanism.

Comment: Admittedly, as things are right now, "I'll do a lot more" is a gross exaggeration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until you amend the question with necessary test cases for various kinds of behavior you desire, here's a trivial proxy that can reverse the string values and strip them of all spaces:

```
class FlexibleProxy : public QIdentityProxyModel {
public:
  enum {
    StripSpaces = 0x1,
    Reverse = 0x2
  } Operation;
  Q_DECLARE_FLAGS(Operations, Operation)
private:
  Operations m_ops;
public:
  FlexibleProxy(Operations ops, QObject * parent = 0) :
    QIdentityProxyModel(parent), m_ops(ops) {}
  QVariant data(QModelIndex & index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const Q_DECL_OVERRIDE {
    auto val = QIdentityProxyModel::data(index, role);
    if ((role == Qt::DisplayRole || role == Qt::EditRole) 
        && val.userType() == QMetaType::QString) {
      auto str = val.toString();
      if (m_ops & StripSpaces) str.remove(QLatin1Char(' '));
      if (m_ops & Reverse) reverse(str);
      val.setValue(str);
    }
    return val;
  }
};
Q_DECLARE_OPERATORS_FOR_FLAGS(FlexibleProxy::Operations)

static void reverse(QString & str) {
  auto const size = str.size();
  for (int i = 0; i <= size/2; ++i) {
    std::swap(str[i], str[size-i]);
  }
}
```

Use:

```
FlexibleProxy proxy{FlexibleProxy::Reverse | FlexibleProxy::StripSpaces};
proxy.setSourceModel(...);
view.setModel(&proxy);
```

Comment: Does your upvote (I'm assuming it was yours) of the other answer and the lack of any change to your own mean that you're telling me the other answer will work for me?

Comment: @user2962533 There's nothing particularly special about either answer: both work, the other one is way more verbose and has some sad anti-patterns. It should be obvious, I hope, that both do the exact same thing. I had hoped that you've got this working and moved on already - if you need clarification on anything else, please edit your question or ask a new one.

Answer (score 1):

As you are not in need of data filtering (as per your OP), you could use `QIdentityProxyModel`. Here are all the classes along with the screenshot

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "basemodel.h"
#include "identitymodel.h"

#include <QTableView>
#include <QBoxLayout>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    QWidget* cWidget = new QWidget(this);
    setCentralWidget(cWidget);

    IdentityModel* normalModel = new IdentityModel(IdentityModel::UnModified, cWidget);
    IdentityModel* reverseModel = new IdentityModel(IdentityModel::Reverse, cWidget);
    IdentityModel* noSpaceModel = new IdentityModel(IdentityModel::NoSpace, cWidget);

    normalModel->setSourceModel(&BaseModel::instance());
    reverseModel->setSourceModel(&BaseModel::instance());
    noSpaceModel->setSourceModel(&BaseModel::instance());

    QTableView* view1 = new QTableView(cWidget);
    QTableView* view2 = new QTableView(cWidget);
    QTableView* view3 = new QTableView(cWidget);

    view1->setModel(normalModel);
    view2->setModel(reverseModel);
    view3->setModel(noSpaceModel);

    QHBoxLayout* hLayout = new QHBoxLayout(cWidget);
    hLayout->addWidget(view1);
    hLayout->addWidget(view2);
    hLayout->addWidget(view3);
}
```

---

basemodel.h

```
    #ifndef BASEMODEL_H
    #define BASEMODEL_H

    #include <QStringListModel>

    class BaseModel : public QStringListModel
    {
        Q_OBJECT

    public:

        static BaseModel& instance()
        {
            static BaseModel sInstance;
            return sInstance;
        }

        virtual int rowCount(const QModelIndex& parent) const
        {
            Q_UNUSED(parent);

            return m_dataList.size();
        }

        virtual QVariant data(const QModelIndex& modelIndex, int role) const;

    signals:

    public slots:

    private:

        explicit BaseModel(QObject* prnt=0);

        QStringList         m_dataList;
    };

    #endif // BASEMODEL_H
```

basemodel.cpp

```
    #include "basemodel.h"

    BaseModel::BaseModel(QObject* prnt)
        : QStringListModel(prnt),
          m_dataList({"Hello World", "Good Bye World"})
    {
    }

    QVariant BaseModel::data(const QModelIndex& modelIndex, int role) const
    {
        if (modelIndex.isValid() && modelIndex.row() < m_dataList.size() && role == Qt::DisplayRole) {
            return m_dataList.at(modelIndex.row());
        }
        return QVariant();
    }
```

---

identitymodel.h

```
#define IDENTITYMODEL_H

#include <QIdentityProxyModel>

class IdentityModel : public QIdentityProxyModel
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:

    enum StringMod
    {
        UnModified,
        Reverse,
        NoSpace
    };

    explicit IdentityModel(StringMod mod, QObject* prnt=0);

    virtual QVariant data(const QModelIndex& proxyIndex, int role) const;

signals:

public slots:

private:

    StringMod       m_stringMod;
};
```

---

identitymodel.cpp

```
#include "identitymodel.h"    
#include <algorithm>

IdentityModel::IdentityModel(StringMod mod, QObject* prnt)
    : QIdentityProxyModel(prnt),
      m_stringMod(mod)
{
}

QVariant IdentityModel::data(const QModelIndex& proxyIndex, int role) const
{
    QVariant dataToModify(QIdentityProxyModel::data(proxyIndex, role));
    if (role == Qt::DisplayRole && m_stringMod != UnModified) {
        QString str(dataToModify.toString());
        if (m_stringMod == NoSpace)
            return str.remove(' ');
        else {
            QByteArray ba(str.toUtf8());
            std::reverse(ba.data(), ba.data() + str.length());
            str = QString(ba);
        }
        return str;
    }
    return dataToModify;
}
```

[image: ProxyModel]

Comment: Please don't use `QMainWindow` where a `QDialog` or even a `QWidget` would do. It's pointless. A `QMainWindow` isn't "main" in any special sense. It's supports docking widgets. If you don't need that, don't use it.

Comment: Honestly, it's absurd to derive from a class just to turn it into a singleton. Completely unnecessary - it's a horrible anti-pattern.

Comment: @KubaOber, how do you do a singleton then? Thanks

Comment: You don't do a singleton. Singletons are useful in very few, specific cases, such as loggers. In most code I look at on SO, singletons are used when someone has no idea how to define and pass around some context. You don't need your model to be a singleton. It should be a variable within `main`, or a member of the widget class.